# Raspberry Pi バックグラウンドでWAVの再生ができない

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Piで起動時にLED点灯とWAVファイルの再生を自動で行いたいのですが、
`/etc/rc.local`で以下ファイルを実行させてもLED点灯までで止まってしまいます。

```
import pygame
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(2,True)

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(sample.wav)
pygame.mixer.music.play(1)

time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

waveファイルを以下のように **絶対パス** で指定してみてください。

```
pygame.mixer.music.load("/path/to/sample.wav")
```

単にファイル名だけを指定した場合、実行したスクリプトと同じディレクトリにwavファイルが存在しないとうまく動かないでしょう。`/etc/rc.local` に(wavファイルを)置くのはおすすめできないので、任意のディレクトリに置いたものをスクリプトから指定してください。